# What are benefit to use library module in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have read some sample codes, I find that many project use library module structure, you can see Image A.

Could you tell me the benefit to use library module in Android Studio ?

What code do I need to place it in library ?

And More, both *app* and *lib* module use the same namesapce in the sample code, I don't know if it's suitable, could you tell me ?

**Image A**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Library module gives you two options to create library Android and Java.

1. **Android library module**->  Android library compiles into an Android Archive (AAR) file that you can use as a dependency for an Android app module . It allows you to add android specific components like resources and manifest file, which allows you to bundle in shared resources like layouts and drawables in addition to Java classes and methods.
2. **Java Library** -> It builds a JAR file. JAR file is useful for many projects especially when you want to share code with other platforms. But it does not allow you to include Android resources or manifest files, which is very useful for code reuse in Android projects. So when you do not need any android specific resources in library you should create a java library.

Library modules are beneficial for projects :-

1. When you're building multiple apps that use some of the same components, such as activities, services, or UI layouts.
2. When you're building an app that exists in multiple APK variations, such as a free and paid version and you need the same core components in both.

Quoted from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library)

Other than that same namespace is not problematic unless you have same package name inside App and libraries . You should use a different namespace for libraries.

**PS**-> If you are familiar with [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html), The idea behind most of the software design pattern is  `Separation of concern` . In Clean architecture a project is divided into multiple modules. When you implement clean architecture in android you'll see that some of the module you can create as `Java library` like `domain module`. Creating module is really useful to follow re-usability and `SOLID` principles and Inversion of control.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't look into the package name declared in the `java` directory. Look into the manifest file. You can see that these modules have different package name. It means that all modules in a project must have different package name.

[image]

Regarding to your question, what are the benefit of naming library module as `lib`?

There's no benefit at all. Some people are comfort with `lib` name, so they can differentiate the **demo** and **library** module easily. However, using `lib` as library's module name requires you to add additional configuration in the `lib/build.gradle`, i.e. `archiveBaseName`. This Gradle attribute will rename the JAR/AAR from `lib.aar` to `work-runtime.aar`, so people can use it like this:

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
```

If `archiveBaseName` is not set, people will use it like this:

```
implementation "androidx.work:lib:$work_version"
```

In real case, let's take my open source library as the example, [MaterialPreference](https://github.com/anggrayudi/MaterialPreference). I used to use `lib` name on this project, but now I think `lib` is not a good module name. Using `materialpreference` as module name will remove additional configuration `archiveBaseName`. So I feel it is more simple.